# notifyDataSetChanged on BaseAdapter without updated data in array

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains times for each item. I display the time to the left, and the time left to the right.
So, let's say I want to display 6.00 p.m. and it is now 4.53 pm, I would display 1 hour and 7 minutes left. This is computed into my BaseAdapter.

Now I would like to refresh these time left every 30 seconds.
So I tried to use a handler with a runnable and call notifyDataSetChanged() but I think, the data needs to be updated otherwise notifyDataSetChanged() does nothing, right?

So here are some pieces of code:

Runnable in my activity:

```
private Runnable updateScreen = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
                    //update of the current time
        rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeNow = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        if(adapter != null)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
    }
};
```

Here is how I instanciate my Adapter in my Activity:

```
adapter = new TimesAdapter(context, times, timeNow);
```

times is a String[] and timeNow is an int.

Do you have some ideas?
Please tell me if you need more pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t call notifyDataSetChanged() from outside the ui thread. Move the call to the handler and the list should refresh.

Comment: Hum, I don't understand... How can I can move the call to the handler? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Really? Nobody can help me? :(